# Create udev rules to run a shell script after insert an USB device

Tags: shell-script, usb, udev, tty, usb-device

Actually, I have two lines of rules in my rules.d folder:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="23b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0005", SYMLINK+="ttyACM-Daruma", MODE="0777"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1753", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c902", SYMLINK+="ttyACM-Gertec", MODE="0777"
```

These persistant symbolic links are used by my POS application and are working fine, but I need to create another rule to execute a custom shell script wheen the user insert the first device (ttyACM-Daruma). Is there any way to achieve this task?

Comment: `man udev`, have a look at `RUN`, in particular the restrictions. If your custom shell script needs to anything outside the restrictions, you'll have to start the script from some kind of demon, and contact the demon in the `RUN` script.

Comment: To be more specific, I need to kill all Wine applications using "wineserver -k" when the user power off the printer (USB device). After that, I need to restart the applications when the user power on the printer.

Comment: Restarting applications definitely won't work, so I'd go with the "write a demon to do the real work, trigger it from an udev script" approach.